# Warning: simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this code

```
<?php

$url = "_configurations/right_sidebar_links.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->links as $links)
{
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='".$links->url."'>";
    echo $links->name."</a></li>";
}

?>
```

that loads xml links from another file, it works fine with links that doesn't have any strange characters but when you enter long link with weird characters it gives an error that is saying

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: _configurations/right_sidebar_links.xml:17: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' in .../includes/loadLinks.php on line 8
```

any help would be much appreciated.

here is an example of the link

http://www.exampe.com/gp/product/B007RT6OZW/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B007RT6OZW&linkCode=as2&tag=backpaininfor-20

Thanks!

Comment: Specify _weird characters_ .. , and a portion of the XML with the _weird characters_, somewhere around and about the lines the error is pointing to.

Comment: here is an example link
http://www.example.com/gp/product/B007RT6OZW/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B007RT6OZW&linkCode=as2&tag=backpaininfor-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of your XML file are invalid.  Make sure it's properly encoded (ie `&` is `&amp;`) and/or `CDATA` tags are used where necessary.

If you open the XML file in a modern browser, they'll usually give you a detailed answer as to where the error is (line and character).

Also, see [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540969/763468)

Comment: Thanks for your tip, i tried in firefox and it gave this

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: link location
Line Number 17, Column 80:

Comment: Well, what does it say on line 17?

Comment: the long url i posted above in the end of the question

Comment: The `&`s need to be `&amp;`s, as previously stated.

Comment: I checked the link you posted, the problem is some links has to have the same signs as is not replaced by the html of it, so i wanted to pass the link as it was written